# DataGrid edition 'EditItem' is not allowed for this view` when bound to a WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I've been reading about this at least for 4 hours, and seems to be the list type, but I have a situation:

A ObservableCollection that has a collection property.

I define the first DataGrid, and in the section

```xml
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <!-- second Datagrid here, binding to Level2 property of my Observable collection -->
    </DataTemplate>
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

Everything goes fine, all things on screen as I expected... but:

1. If try to modify DataGrid1 cells it allow me.
2. If try to modify DataGrid2 cells it throw me this exception `'EditItem' is not allowed for this view`

What am I missing ?

This is my model:

```cs
public partial class Level1
{
    public Level1()
    {
        this.Level2 = new HashSet<Level2>();
    }

    public decimal IdLevel1 { get; set; }
    public decimal IdLevel2 { get; set; }
    public string StrDescripcionTipoAsociado {get;set;}

    public virtual Level2 Level2{ get; set; }
}

public partial class Level2
{
    public decimal IdLevel1 { get; set; }
    public decimal IdLevel3 { get; set; }

    public virtual Level3 Level3{ get; set; }
}

public partial class Level3
{
    public decimal IdLevel3 { get; set; }
    public decimal NumIdConcepto {get;set;}
    public string StrDescripcionConcepto {get;set;}
}
```

EDIT: XAML Code:

```xml
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Level1}" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              SelectionMode="Single"
              GridLinesVisibility="Vertical"
              CanUserAddRows="True"
              CanUserDeleteRows="True"
              x:Name="GridTipoAsociado">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Tipo de asociado" x:Name="TipoUsuarioSeleccionado">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=FontElemNivel1}" Content="{Binding StrDescripcionTipoAsociado}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=FontElemNivel2}" Text="{Binding StrDescripcionTipoAsociado }"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Level2}" 
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                          SelectionMode="Single"
                          SelectionUnit="Cell"
                          GridLinesVisibility="Vertical"
                          CanUserAddRows="True"
                          CanUserDeleteRows="True"                            
                          x:Name="GridItems">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Id Item">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding NumIdConcepto}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Items">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding Level3.StrDescripcionConcepto}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Level3.StrDescripcionConcepto}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Can you post the xaml for DataGrid2 and code behind for its itemsSource collection?

Comment: Yes I'm going to publish the xaml, But I don't have any code behind.

Comment: Level3.StrDescripcionConcepto. where is this property?

Comment: Sorry lost it in my model sample

Comment: how can you bind ItemsSource to a single object ItemsSource="{Binding Level2}" ? It should be collection

Comment: Now my sample model is ok.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36671/discussion-between-juan-pablo-gomez-and-nit)

Comment: bro i tried it and it worked fine at my end :(...i might need your actual xaml code to crack it

Comment: @nit Tks, ther it is on chat room, sorry for the delay but i'm was on launch hour

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tks to @nit who give me the right path. Of course the problem reside on the base Type of EF collections

**Hashet< T >**  And Datagrid need at least a **List< T >**, changing all my classes "those generated by Entity framework", give to me another problem, must make changes manually, and I have a lot of them.

My solution was to create a converter, that made the dirty work for me:

```
public class listToObservableCollection : BaseConverter, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        HashSet<Level2> observableList = (HashSet<Level2>)value;
        return new ObservableCollection<Level2>(observableList);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (HashSet<Level2>)value;
    }
}

public abstract class BaseConverter : MarkupExtension
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

And put it on the binding of my Datagrid2:

```
<!--part of my window definition--!>
xmlns:l="clr-namespace:Recursos;assembly=Recursos"
...
<!--part of my resources section--!>
<l:listToObservableCollection x:Key="listoToObservable"/>
...
<!--part of my datagrid definition--!>
ItemsSource="{Binding Level2,Converter={StaticResource listoToObservable}}"
```

The only thing on the air is how to make a generic converter,  but for now it works fine.

Comment: I've tried that, but i'm having an error in the following line in the xaml : ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ModeloItensViewSource}, Converter={StaticResource collectionConverter}}". The error is "value cannot be null. Parameter name: Collection".

Comment: @Marlon Sorry for the delay, jsut some days of vacation. did you define ``ModeloItensViewSource`` properly ? why it is a static resource ?

Comment: I've just see done that way in some example in the internet. But i have gave up on entity framework for this project. I was having too much errors and problems, and it was too much work for a small project. Maybe later i'll take some time to study it better. But thanks for the attention anyway.

Comment: Some things give loot after the effort, and EF is one of them. Maybe EF Isn't the problema, could be the design, are you using MVVM as a development pattern?.
I was about 2 months having many problems, and now I am enjoying the versatility and power  of EF and MVVM. is an effort that justifies long term. Just tell me if you need more help.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. Probably the problem is more like you said really, more with the design than with EF. But for the size of the project and the time it would take to study that it wouldn't be worthy. But i'll certainly look at it for future projects.

Answer (score 22):

I tried this and the problem is that you have initialized your Level2 collection as `Hashset<>`. `IEditableCollectionView.EditItem()` throws this error while trying to update item in `Hashset<>`.
I initialized the collection as `List<>` and it was working fine.

I am not sure why it is not able to update item in hashset, need to look deeper into it. But changing the `Hashset<>` to `List<>` will fix this error.

Hope it helps

Thanks

Comment: The reason is because binding a `Datagrid`'s itemsource to `Hashset` doesn't generate a collection view that implements `IEditableCollectionView`. `List` will generate a `ListCollectionView` which _does_ implement this interface, which is why it works.

Comment: This code is auto generated by EF, could this change affect performance. Or other issues on my relational model.? If not why EF define collections as hashet?

Comment: @nit very tks for your help, now I need to fight with EF generation code, to maintain my classes generated with List instead Hashet. Again very very tks for your help.

Comment: This clued me into my problem; in my case I was just dumb and had bound the grid to the result of a LINQ query. The solution was simply to add .ToList() to the end of it.

Answer (score 13):

You might try this. Attach a BeginningEdit handler to your DataGrid and point to this code:

```
    private void Grid_BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
    {
        //// Have to do this in the unusual case where the border of the cell gets selected.
        //// and causes a crash 'EditItem is not allowed'
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

This will only hit if you somehow manage to physically tap down on the border of the cell. The event's OriginalSource is a Border, and I think what may happen here is, instead of a TextBox or other editable element being the source as expected, this un-editable Border comes through for editing, which causes an exception that is buried in the 'EditItem is not allowed' exception. Canceling this RoutedEvent before it can bubble on through with its invalid OriginalSource stops that error occurring in its tracks.

Comment: This approach worked fine for me. I also added a little "twist" to make it more narrow:

MyGrid.BeginningEdit += 
(sender, args) => args.Cancel = args.EditingEventArgs.OriginalSource is Border;

Comment: That's a good additional check and I considered at the time, but it wasn't quite necessary for our UI.

Answer (score 7):

I also solved this problem by using `IsReadOnly="True"`.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a generic Converter that I used

```
public class ObservableCollectionConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var observableType= typeof (ObservableCollection<>).MakeGenericType(value.GetType().GetGenericArguments());
        return Activator.CreateInstance(observableType, value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var observableType = typeof(HashSet<>).MakeGenericType(value.GetType().GetGenericArguments());
        return Activator.CreateInstance(observableType, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In shorter way you can write:

```
DataGrid.BeginningEdit += (s, ss) => ss.Cancel = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Seeing has no-one has posted this, the answer is because the collection you are binding to needs to implement `IList` (and possibly `ICollection`).

It is due to the non-generic (think `object`) nature of `DataGrid` (and also `CollectionView` I believe).

Answer (score 1):

you can set IsReadOnly property. maybe Exception not occur...
try it in xaml file..

```
IsReadOnly="True"
```

Answer (score -3):

I resolved this putting my datagrid in readonly mode

```
<DataGrid 
                Name="dtgBulkInsert"
                CanUserSortColumns="True" 
                Height="300" Visibility="Collapsed" IsReadOnly="True">
```

....