# Binding ObservableCollection to DataGrid

Tags: wpf, .net-4.5

How do I bind a `ObservableCollection<updateData>` `updateCollection` to a `DataGrid`? I tried several solution but none seem to work as rows are added to the collection but don't show up on the grid. I tried to bind to the class only, then I can add rows but when I try to edit them i get the error `'EditItem' is not allowed for this view`. The grid is the following

```
<DataGrid Name="dgv" Grid.ColumnSpan="7"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding updateCollection}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" CanUserAddRows="False">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Hour" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Active}" ItemsSource="{StaticResource hoursList}" DisplayMemberPath="Key" SelectedValuePath="Value"/>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Origin" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Origin}" ItemsSource="{StaticResource originList}" DisplayMemberPath="Key" SelectedValuePath="Value"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="P" Binding="{Binding Path=Price}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Q" Binding="{Binding Path=Quantity}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

And the `updateData` class is the following:

```
public class updateData
{
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Origin { get; set; }
    public string Hour { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What `DataContext` DataGrid uses?

Comment: Have you seen this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578254/datagrid-edition-edititem-is-not-allowed-for-this-view-when-bound-to-a-wpf-da ?

Comment: @ASh I tried setting `dgv.DataContext = updateCollection` but it didnt change anything.

Comment: @Hauba, if you are goind to use binding for `ItemsSource`, `DataContext` should be an object which has `updateCollection` property. Without DataContext it will work if `ItemsSource` is set directly: `dgv.ItemsSource = updateCollection`

Comment: @ASh I set the item source directly and it solved all my problems, if you leave an anwser I can accpet it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you did looks correct, but if you miss one single thing, the `DataContext`… nothing will work.
Here an example just for you:

This is your Model:

```
public class updateData
{
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Origin { get; set; }
    public string Hour { get; set; }
}
```

Note that, if you want to tell to your view that something has changed, you have to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

This is your ViewModel:

```
public class updateDataVm
{
    public ObservableCollection<updateData> updateCollection { get; set; }

    public updateDataVm()
    {
        updateCollection = new ObservableCollection<updateData>(); 
    }
}
```

And finally here is your View (note that i have changed `ItemsSource` to `ItemsSource="{Binding}"`):

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="dgv" Grid.ColumnSpan="7"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" CanUserAddRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Hour" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Active}" ItemsSource="{StaticResource hoursList}" DisplayMemberPath="Key" SelectedValuePath="Value"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Origin" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Origin}" ItemsSource="{StaticResource originList}" DisplayMemberPath="Key" SelectedValuePath="Value"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="P" Binding="{Binding Path=Price}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Q" Binding="{Binding Path=Quantity}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

In your window (or generally control):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public updateDataVm collection;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        collection = new updateDataVm();
        DataContext = collection;
    }
}
```