# Double click on selected row in datagrid does not work properly

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create tree when user click on a row of table
This is the code of selection changed

```
     private void Row_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridRow row = sender as DataGridRow;
        // Some operations with this row
        if (row != null)
        {
            var item = row.DataContext as Processes;
            if (item != null)
            {
                int id = item.ID;
                var subModules = new List<ITreeNode>();
                var subThreads = new List<ITreeNode>();
                for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
                {
                    subThreads.Add(new SubThread { Name = "subthread" + i });
                }
                var nodes = new List<ITreeNode>
    {
        new Thread { Name = "Thread ", ChildNodes = subThreads },
        new Module { Name = "Module ", ChildNodes = subModules }
    };
                var runprocesses = new List<RunProcesses>();
                Process myProcess = Process.GetProcessById(id);
                ProcessModule myProcessModule;
                //Get all the modules associated with 'myProcess".
                ProcessModuleCollection myProcessModuleCollection = myProcess.Modules;
                for (int i = 0; i < myProcessModuleCollection.Count; i++)
                {
                    myProcessModule = myProcessModuleCollection[i];
                    string s = myProcessModule.FileName;
                    if (i == 1)
                    {
                        runprocesses.Add(new RunProcesses { Name = myProcessModule.FileName, ChildNodes = nodes });
                    }

                    subModules.Add(new SubModule { Name = s });
                    //Console.WriteLine("The moduleName is " + myProcessModule.ModuleName);
                }

                TreeView.ItemsSource = runprocesses;

            }
        }
}
```

Add double click event handler to system

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Style rowStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridRow));
        rowStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(DataGridRow.MouseDoubleClickEvent,
                                 new MouseButtonEventHandler(Row_DoubleClick)));
        dg.RowStyle = rowStyle;//dg is the name of datagrid
    }
```

When I doubleclick on any row of table output is Source information is missing from the debug information for this module and System.InvalidOperationException: ''EditItem' is not allowed for this view.'
I have searched from various links that explain the reason and solution of this problem but no one resolve my problem.
I am unable to understand where I am wrong. Kindly guide me how to resolve this problem.

Comment: add a try/catch,...see what the error is...the issue might not be with the external processes

Comment: I add try/catch in this function but no exception throws and in output of system it throws one exception An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
'EditItem' is not allowed for this view.    Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: 'EditItem' is not allowed for this view.

Comment: See this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578254/datagrid-edition-edititem-is-not-allowed-for-this-view-when-bound-to-a-wpf-da