# How to enable cell editing for Datagrid in Powershell?

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml, datagrid, powershell-3.0

I am looking for the solution how to enable cell editing and adding of new cells when double clicking on the items in a wpf datagrid view.

I am actually not able to trace where I have done the mistake. Whenever I am double clicking on the item it throws error as "Editing is not allowed" and windows form gets closed automatically.

Question: Could you please help with the below code how to enable editing for WPF datagrid on mouse double click event?

```
[xml]$XAML = @'
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Server Rebuild Request" Height="600" Width="1000" Background="White" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Background="White">

    <Grid
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">


    <Grid>
   <DataGrid Name="Datagrid" IsReadOnly="False" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" CanUserReorderColumns="True" CanUserSortColumns="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowBackground="#D1F29C" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible" Cursor="Hand"  >


        <DataGrid.Columns >


           <DataGridTextColumn Header="TaskName" IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding TaskName}" Width="100" Foreground="#FF631F1F" />
           <DataGridTextColumn Header="Category" IsReadOnly="False" Binding="{Binding Category}" Width="100" Foreground="#FF631F1F" />


            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Status}" Width="80" Foreground="#FF631F1F"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Created By" Binding="{Binding 'Created By'}" Width="100" Foreground="#FF631F1F"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Asigned To" Binding="{Binding 'Asigned To'}" Width="100" Foreground="#FF631F1F"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Dead Line" Binding="{Binding 'Dead Line'}" Width="90" Foreground="#FF631F1F"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding 'Age'}" Width="50" Foreground="#FF631F1F"/>
            <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Source URL" Binding="{Binding 'Source URL'}" Width="300" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Action">


                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox 
                                    Height="22" >

                                    <ComboBoxItem AllowDrop="True" Content="'In Progress','Done'" IsSelected="False"/>
                                </ComboBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>

                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>



                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>

                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>


                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>


        </DataGrid.Columns>



    </DataGrid>
    </Grid>



</Grid>


    </Grid>
</Window>
'@


#Read XAML
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 
try{$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )}
catch{Write-Host "Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader. Some possible causes for this problem include: .NET Framework is missing PowerShell must be launched with PowerShell -sta, invalid XAML code was encountered."; exit}

$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name)}

$Datagrid.RowStyle=[System.Windows.Style]::new()
$Datagrid.IsEnabled=$true
#$Datagrid.is
$DataGrid.AddChild([pscustomobject]@{TaskName='Test1';Category='CTB';Status='InProgress'; 'Created By'='TestCode'; 'Asigned To'='TestCode'; 'Dead Line'=$DeadLine; Age=$Age; 'Source URL'=$href})
$DataGrid.AddChild([pscustomobject]@{TaskName='Test2';Category='CTB';Status='InProgress'; 'Created By'='TestCode'; 'Asigned To'='TestCode'; 'Dead Line'=$DeadLine; Age=$Age; 'Source URL'=$href})
$DataGrid.AddChild([pscustomobject]@{TaskName=$null;Category=$null;Status=$null; 'Created By'=$null; 'Asigned To'=$null; 'Dead Line'=$DeadLine; Age=$Age; 'Source URL'=$href})



$Datagrid.Add_Mousedoubleclick({
Write-Host "Mouse double clicked"
$Datagrid.Items.EditItem($Datagrid.SelectedItem)
})


$Form.ShowDialog()
```

The error I am getting when double clicking on item.

Exception calling "ShowDialog" with "0" argument(s): "'EditItem' is not allowed for this view."
At C:\Users\bbiswal041119\Downloads\RDS_News_Letter\TestDataGrid.ps1:97 char:1
+ $Form.ShowDialog()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the `Edit` experience in a Datagrid, you have to specify the `.ItemsSource` for the Grid using that method.  This works because this will implement the `IEditable` interface, needed for that experience.

Note that I commented out your `$DataGrid.AddChild` lines.

```
$itemsArray = @([pscustomobject]@{TaskName='Test1';Category='CTB';Status='InProgress'; 'Created By'='TestCode'; 'Asigned To'='TestCode'; 'Dead Line'=$DeadLine; Age=$Age; 'Source URL'=$href},
    [pscustomobject]@{TaskName='Test2';Category='CTB';Status='InProgress'; 'Created By'='TestCode'; 'Asigned To'='TestCode'; 'Dead Line'=$DeadLine; Age=$Age; 'Source URL'=$href},
    [pscustomobject]@{TaskName=$null;Category=$null;Status=$null; 'Created By'=$null; 'Asigned To'=$null; 'Dead Line'=$DeadLine; Age=$Age; 'Source URL'=$href}
)
$Datagrid.ItemsSource = $itemsArray
#$DataGrid.AddChild([pscustomobject]@{TaskName='Test1';Category='CTB';Status='InProgress'; 'Created By'='TestCode'; 'Asigned To'='TestCode'; 'Dead Line'=$DeadLine; Age=$Age; 'Source URL'=$href})
#$DataGrid.AddChild([pscustomobject]@{TaskName='Test2';Category='CTB';Status='InProgress'; 'Created By'='TestCode'; 'Asigned To'='TestCode'; 'Dead Line'=$DeadLine; Age=$Age; 'Source URL'=$href})
#$DataGrid.AddChild([pscustomobject]@{TaskName=$null;Category=$null;Status=$null; 'Created By'=$null; 'Asigned To'=$null; 'Dead Line'=$DeadLine; Age=$Age; 'Source URL'=$href})
```

And here's how it looks : 
[image]

You can read some more about why this is needed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578254/datagrid-edition-edititem-is-not-allowed-for-this-view-when-bound-to-a-wpf-da), or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/binding-sources-overview#using-entire-objects-as-a-binding-source).

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. You have solved my problem. I was not aware of this. I was always trying to add through AddChild Method.